# Using JavaScript in Blazor 8.0

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-8

I am trying to use Blazor 8.0 with Auto (Server & WebAssembly) and Interactive as Global. I am using Jscript in App.Razor file but they are not working. Its latest update and I am not sure how to use these files in project. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Oh well, please be more precise - what have you tried / received as error messages / etc. -> The more details you provide the better you will be able to get someone helping you ...

Comment: No error, Jscript just not working.

Comment: I just want to know where exactly i have to place this line:
<script src="assets/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: I am **still** having issues with your attitude towards this site and their respective users ---- Nevertheless --- the following linked solution is one possible way/path to follow --- [Your solution link](https://gprivate.com/67ms8)

Comment: Please provide a lot more information about what you're trying to do - in particular, what project type you're using. 
If you can provide a minimal reproducible example, including both the C# code and the project file, 
we're much more likely to be able to help you.
show us some code that you've tried and explain what's not working about it and we'll be better able to help you.

Comment: I create a JS file (Myscrpit.js)  and put it inside wwwroot folder, then place this line:  `<script src="Myscrpit.js"></script>` in  App.Razor file. It works.  It would be better if you could give an example.